# Cashier issue - subscription table not populated with checkout subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-10

I'm using stripe checkout (Laravel v.10 and Cashier v.14), and after a successful stripe checkout subscription (payment/customer data are created on stripe dashboard), the subscriptions table is not being populated (development mode). This used to work before.

Webhooks are working fine (CLI) too.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Are you aware of any bugs or configuration not documented?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is either that you're using the API keys from a different Stripe account, or you're not in `mode: 'subscription'` when you think you are. The best option is to look at the exact payload in the `checkout.session.completed` Event and check that you see a `subscription: 'sub_123'` property. You'll be better off talking to Stripe's support team though as they can look into your account directly to help: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I deleted the stripe testing account and created one from scratch. Replaced the .env with new credentials and everything is fine now.